# Excel dropdown list that automatically fills areas in another sheet

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I can't figure this out, need your help, please.

I have four sheets in the same document.

**Sheet 1** and **2** are for **Banks**, **Sheet 3** and **4** are a **personal Vault** and a **Trust Fund**, respectively.

Banks 1 and 2 are the **Sources** and the Vault and the Trust Fund are the **Destinations**.

On the **Banks Sheets** there are these categories:

**Date, Withdrawal, Destination**. And in the **Destination** cells i have a **dropdown list** with the values **"Vault"** and **"Trust Fund"**.

On the **Vault** and the **Trust Fund** Sheets I have:

**Date, Incoming, Source**. And in the **Source** cells i have a **dropdown list** with the values **"Bank 1"** and **"Bank 2".**

What i need is this: When i go to the **Bank 1** sheet and fill in the **Date** with, let's say, **06/2013**, and **Withdrawal** with **100.00**, when i choose **Vault** from the **Destination dropdown list**, these same values would then appear in the respective fields on the **Vault** sheet, in the next available line of cells of that sheet, with the difference that instead of the column **Withdrawal**, the 100.00 would be in **Incoming** (because there isn't a Withdrawal column in Vault).

And, of course, since I chose **Vault** from the **Bank 1** sheet, the value **Bank 1** would now be in the field of the dropdown list of the column **Source** in the **Vault Sheet**.

So, that would be the idea: i would fill in the fields in the **Sources Sheet** and if i choose the **Destination** to be the **Vault**, these values would then appear in the **Vault**'s field, indicating that they are coming from that exact **Source**. However, if i choose the destination to be the **Trust Fund**, the same would happen, but with the **Trust Fund** value and Sheet.

Is this remotely possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a dropdown list (data validation) for every line?

Comment: yes, but only on the Destination and Source Cateories.  If you need me to do dropdown lists for every category i can do that, as well.

Comment: Is it important to maintain a certain chronological order or bank priority in Vault/Trust Fund listings? If there are several rows in Bank 1 and Bank 2, can they have separate columns in Vault/Trust or should have interleaving rows? Can the entries in Vault/Trust shift relative positions depending on existence of other data in the source?

Comment: Chronological order is important, because it will be used as a sort of a Balance Sheet. But the other things aren't that important. It would be nice to have things as organized as possible, but i know how excel can impose some limitations, so, i'll be glad if things just mantain their chronological order. Thanks for your help, Jüri.